# Service Discovery Error on Spring Boot and Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am learning the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. I have designed a very simple app for Eureka server. My POM is given below--

---

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>service-discovery-ha</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>service-discovery-high-availability</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Serivice Discovery</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR1</version>
            <type>POM</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I am getting the following error--

> 17:12:48.491 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>       at

I am getting the error to Maven install and Spring Boot run-time. My guess is it's dependency error. Is there any thing else apart from it? I am not able to figure out.
And what does this error mean?
Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Camden - Finchley is not compatible with boot 2.1.0. We will release a version that is compatible soon.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me which version of Spring Boot is compatible with Camden?

Comment: Camden is no longer supported, but I think it was boot 1.4.x. Edgware is compatible with boot 1.5.x, Finchley with boot 2.0.x and forthcoming Greenwich RC1 with boot 2.1.0

Comment: Thanks. Some improvement. I am using the following spring cloud dependency <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version> . I am able to clean and install in Maven. But when I run in the Sprring-Boot app.

Comment: It's give me the following error---         
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
 at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
 at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApp

Comment: Am I missing something in my POM file? Help please!!

Comment: try greenwich.m2 ?

Comment: Thanks to all. It's working fine for me now. You guys save my life.